# Bloomberg API get all own deals (trades)

Tags: java, api, bloomberg, forex

I am trying to use Bloomber Api from [http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/](http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries).
I have observed all the examples of API usage on Java, but couldn't find command to get all own deals(trades). 
Could you guys suggest or show piece of code to get such result.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is [Off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO, perhaps reach out to the API support team or check on Quora?

Comment: I don't think that's available in that API. If you are using EMSX there is a separate API I believe. Have you asked Bloomberg's HELP HELP?